# Unhandled exception in vb app using dts runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I have a vb application that uses a click event to set off a SSIS package located on a sql 2008r2 x86 server.  Both the sql server and the integration services are 32bit.  The vb app is 32bit but I still get the following error message:

*Unhandled exception occurred in your application...  Microsoft.SQLServer.DTS.Runtime.DtsComException: An Integration Services class cannot be found.  Make sure that Integration Services is correctly installed on the computer that is running the application.  Also, make sure that the 64bit version of the Integration Services is installed if you are running a 64bit application.*

**What exactly is the client computer looking for?  What do I need to install separately or as part of the deployment package to make this work?**

The application runs without error on the dev box where sql everything is installed along with all the visual studio tools.  However, when I deploy it to the end user I get the above message.  Am I understanding the above message to say that I must install integration services on the client machine in order to use Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntime in my application?  If so that seems very clunky.  Not to mention infeasible to install it on hundreds of desktops.

The code in the application is simple and I don't think its the issue, but I'll paste it here in case I'm wrong.

```
Private Sub btnISupplierImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnISupplierImport.Click


    'Executes SSIS job to import customer requirements.
    Dim appReader As New System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader
    Dim app As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application()
    Dim package As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package()
    Dim jobName As String
    Dim ssisServerName As String
    Dim msg As String = "Importing requirements"
    Dim title As String = "Import"
    Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel
    Dim response = MsgBox(msg, style, title)
    If response = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
        Try
            jobName = appReader.GetValue("CustomerRequirementsImportJobName", GetType(System.String))
            ssisServerName = appReader.GetValue("CustomerRequirementImportServerName", GetType(System.String))
            package = app.LoadFromSqlServer(jobName, ssisServerName, "Bob", "Password", Nothing)
            package.Execute()
            MessageBox.Show("Finished Importing")
        Catch ex As DtsException
            'MessageBox.Show(ex)
        End Try
    End If


End Sub
```

Finally, the Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS and Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap references are set to copy local so it is on the user machine but I still get the error.
ANY help on this is greatly appreciated.  I've been struggling with this for over a week and still haven't tamed it.

Comment: I had trouble launching an SSIS package from a .net app.  What worked was to create a job that launches the SSIS package, and launch the job from the .net app with a SQL command.

Comment: Thanks Tab!  That did the trick with a couple lines less of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab's response was a quick fix for my problem.  While I'd still like to know how to fix the original problem, his solution works for me.  Here is the code change that got me going again.

```
Private Sub btnISupplierImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnISupplierImport.Click

    Dim appReader As New System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader
    Dim connectionString As String = CStr(appReader.GetValue("SqlConnection.ConnectionString", GetType(System.String)))
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()

    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    command.CommandText = "sp_start_job"
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_name", "Customer Requirements")
    command.Connection = connection
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

A last note - the connection string had to reference the system msdb database for the sp_start_job stored procedure to fire.

Thanks again Tab